# When opening a terminal, I can't type without clicking it first

Tags: centos, xfce

In Xfce4 with CentOS 6, when I double click on the terminal icon to open the terminal, I can't start typing in it unless I click in the terminal once. It's as if the window is not selected or something. How can this be fixed?  Which setting influences this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Open Settings->Window Manager and go to the Focus tab

There you will find the option "Automatically give focus to newly created windows"